# Implement JHipster with OAuth2 and refresh token

Tags: jhipster

I'm interested is it possible to generate a project with JHipster which has properties like OAuth2 refresh token?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just choose OAuth 2.0 for authentication type when creating your app.

Comment: I checked the code but unformulated I have to use Keyclock server. There is no option to run a project with OAuth2 authentication without Keyclock.

Comment: By the way @Matt do you know how I can run JHipster project with OAuth2 authentication without Keyclock server?

Comment: You have to use some sort of OAuth 2.0 Authorization Server to do OAuth. What server are you hoping to use? JHipster supports Okta and should work with any Identity Provider that supports OpenID Connect.

Comment: I decided to try with  `spring-cloud-starter-oauth2`